# C++ fstream outputs wrong data

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, ofstream

Context first:

My program do some parallel calculation which are logged in a file. Threads are grouped by blocks (I'm using CUDA). The log file is formated this way:

```
#begin run
({blockIdx,threadIdx}) {thread_info}
({blockIdx,threadIdx}) {thread_info}
...
#end run
```

I've wrote a function that should read the log file and sort each run messages by thread.

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Comparison struct for log file sorting
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
typedef struct
{
    bool operator()(const string &rString1 , const string &rString2)
    {
        int closeParenthesisLocalition1 = rString1.find_first_of(')');
        int closeParenthesisLocalition2 = rString2.find_first_of(')');
        int compResult = rString1.compare(0 , closeParenthesisLocalition1 + 2 , rString2 , 0 , closeParenthesisLocalition2 + 2);
        return (compResult < 0);
    }
} comp;

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Sort the log file. Lines with same prefix (blockIdx,ThreadIdx) will be grouped in file per run.
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
void CudaUnitTest::sortFile()
{
    comp comparison;
    deque<string> threadsPrintfs;
    ifstream inputFile(m_strInputFile);
    assert(inputFile.is_open());

    //Read whole input file and close it. Saves disk accesses.
    string strContent((std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(inputFile)), std::istreambuf_iterator<char>());
    inputFile.close();

    ofstream outputFile(m_strOutputFile);
    assert(outputFile.is_open());

    string strLine;
    int iBeginRunIdx = -10; //value just to addapt on while loop (to start on [0])
    int iBeginRunNewLineOffset = 10; //"idx offset to a new line char in string. Starts with the offset of the string "#begin run\n".
    int iEndRunIdx;
    int iLastNewLineIdx;
    int iNewLineIdx;

    while((iBeginRunIdx = strContent.find("#begin run\n" , iBeginRunIdx + iBeginRunNewLineOffset)) != string::npos)
    {
        iEndRunIdx = strContent.find("#end run\n" , iBeginRunIdx + iBeginRunNewLineOffset);
        assert(iEndRunIdx != string::npos);

        iLastNewLineIdx = iBeginRunIdx + iBeginRunNewLineOffset;
        while((iNewLineIdx = strContent.find("\n" , iLastNewLineIdx + 1)) < iEndRunIdx)
        {
            strLine = strContent.substr(iLastNewLineIdx + 1 , iNewLineIdx);
            if(verifyPrefix(strLine))
                threadsPrintfs.push_back(strLine);
            iLastNewLineIdx = iNewLineIdx;
        }

        //sort last run info
        sort(threadsPrintfs.begin() , threadsPrintfs.end() , comparison);
        threadsPrintfs.push_front("#begin run\n");
        threadsPrintfs.push_back("#end run\n");

        //output it
        for(deque<string>::iterator it = threadsPrintfs.begin() ; it != threadsPrintfs.end() ; ++it)
        {
            assert(outputFile.good());
            outputFile.write(it->c_str() , it->size());
        }
        outputFile.flush();
        threadsPrintfs.clear();
    }

    outputFile.close();
}
```

The problem is that the resulting file has a lot of trash data. For example an input log file with 6KB generated a output log of 192KB! It appears the output file has a lot of repetitions of the input file. When debugging code the deque showed the right values before and after sort, though. I think there is something wrong with the ofstream write itself.

Edit: The function isn't running in parallel.

Comment: Are multiple threads writing at the same time?

Comment: do you protect your std::ofs you should. tream invocations with mutexes ?

Comment: @Batchyx: I SEE WHAT and i like YOU DID THERE it.

Comment: This code is after parallel computation. Its serial.

Comment: `substr` accepts a length, not an end index. How come you have correct strings in the deque? In general, fiddling with indices is a very bad idea. Use normal `getline()`. Don't bother with saving file accesses, that's what file buffer is for. Increase your buffer size **if profiling shows that you are wasting time on accessing the file** and be done with it.

Comment: @n.m: what i was about to say, it's the parsing that's borken.

Comment: Now that you pointed, I really misused substr. I'll try changing code and will post results later.

Comment: Yeah. The problem was just that substr don't receive an index but a lenght instead.

Answer (score 0):

Just to show the final code. Note the change on substr, now instead of an index it's receiving the lenght.

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Sort the log file. Lines with same prefix (blockIdx,ThreadIdx) will be grouped in file per run.
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
void CudaUnitTest::sortFile()
{
comp comparison;
deque<string> threadsPrintfs;
ifstream inputFile(m_strInputFile);
assert(inputFile.is_open());

//Read whole input file and close it. Saves disk accesses.
string strContent((std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(inputFile)), std::istreambuf_iterator<char>());
inputFile.close();

ofstream outputFile(m_strOutputFile);
assert(outputFile.is_open());

string strLine;
int iBeginRunIdx = -10; //value just to addapt on while loop (to start on [0])
int iBeginRunNewLineOffset = 10; //"idx offset to a new line char in string. Starts with the offset of the string "#begin run\n".
int iEndRunIdx;
int iLastNewLineIdx;
int iNewLineIdx;

while((iBeginRunIdx = strContent.find("#begin run\n" , iBeginRunIdx + iBeginRunNewLineOffset)) != string::npos)
{
    iEndRunIdx = strContent.find("#end run\n" , iBeginRunIdx + iBeginRunNewLineOffset);
    assert(iEndRunIdx != string::npos);

    iLastNewLineIdx = iBeginRunIdx + iBeginRunNewLineOffset;
    while((iNewLineIdx = strContent.find("\n" , iLastNewLineIdx + 1)) < iEndRunIdx)
    {
        strLine = strContent.substr(iLastNewLineIdx + 1 , iNewLineIdx - iLastNewLineIdx);
        if(verifyPrefix(strLine))
            threadsPrintfs.push_back(strLine);
        iLastNewLineIdx = iNewLineIdx;
    }

    //sort last run info
    sort(threadsPrintfs.begin() , threadsPrintfs.end() , comparison);
    threadsPrintfs.push_front("#begin run\n");
    threadsPrintfs.push_back("#end run\n");

    //output it
    for(deque<string>::iterator it = threadsPrintfs.begin() ; it != threadsPrintfs.end() ; ++it)
    {
        assert(outputFile.good());
        outputFile.write(it->c_str() , it->size());
    }
    threadsPrintfs.clear();
}

outputFile.close();
}
```